# Trouble converting a string from Unicode in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

I'm extremely confused over unicode in Python 2.x.

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape a webpage, and I'm trying to insert the things I find into a dictionary with the name as the key, and the url as the value.

I'm using BeautifulSoup's `find` function to get the info I need. My code started out as follows:

```
name = i.find('a').string
url = i.find('a').get('href')
```

This works, with the exception of the thign returned from `find` is an Object, and not a string.

*Here's were things start confusing me*

If I try to convert it to type `str` before I assign it to the variable, it sometimes throws an `UnicodeEncodeError`.

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I Google around and find that I should be encoding to `ascii`

I try adding:

```
print str(i.find('a').string).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

No luck, still gives an, Unicode Error.

From there, I tried using `repr`.

```
print repr(i.find('a').string)
```

And that works... almost!

I ran into a new problem here.

Once everything is said and done, and the dictionary is built, I can't bloody access anything! It keeps giving me a `KeyError`.

I can loop over the dict:

```
for i in sorted(data.iterkeys()):
    print i


>>> u'Key1'
>>> u'Key2'
>>> u'Key3'
>>> u'Key4'
```

but if I try to access an item of the dict like this:

```
print data['key1']
```

OR

```
print data[u'key1']
```

OR

```
test = unicode('key1')
print data[test]
```

They all return KeyErrors, which is 100% confusing to me. I assume it's got something to do with them being Unicode objects.

I've tried just about everything I can come up with, but I can't figure out what's going on.

Oh! Adding to the oddity, is that this code:

```
name = repr(i.find('a').string)
print type(name)
```

returns

```
>>> type(str)
```

but if I just print the thing

```
print name
```

it shows it as a unicode string

```
>>>> u'string name'
```

Comment: This goes beyond BeautifulSoup, make sure you read (without skipping parts for convenience): http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: about your dictionary issues: are `Key1`, `Key2` and `Key3` really your output, or some code you wrote by hand for this question? Because they are capitalized, so `data['key1']` won't work. Try `data['Key1']` instead ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.string` value is indeed not a string. You need to cast it to `unicode()`:

```
name = unicode(i.find('a').string)
```

It's a unicode-*like* object called [`NavigableString`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring). If you really *need* it to be a `str` instead, you can encode it from there:

```
name = unicode(i.find('a').string).encode('utf8')
```

or similar. For use in a `dict` I'd use `unicode()` objects and not encode.

To understand the difference between `unicode()` and `str()` and what encoding to use, I recommend you read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).